# Programatically determine if IIS site is running or not

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, iis-6, directoryservices

I have a script that gathers up all sites in IIS and emails a few details for auditing. I want to adjust it so that it only emails sites that are running. I do not need to know about sites that are stopped.  I already have a reference to all of the `DirectoryEntry`s in IIS but I don't see any properties that would indicate if it is running or not.

How is this done? Ideally this should run on both IIS6 and IIS7.

Comment: Lame way: use `WebClient` to request the home page and see if you get any kind of response. :/

Comment: DL: I don't think that's lame at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DirectoryEntry.Properties` collection, contains a `ServerState` property. It's not documented very well but I found [this blogger](http://csharp-tipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2009_12_01_archive.html) that created his own enumeration which appears to be correct. The enum is

```
public enum ServerState
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Starting = 1,
    Started = 2,
    Stopping = 3,
    Stopped = 4,
    Pausing = 5,
    Paused = 6,
    Continuing = 7
}
```

Using this, the logic to check if a `DirectoryEntry` is running, you would use:

```
DirectoryEntry entry;
ServerState state = (ServerState)Enum.Parse(typeof(ServerState), entry.Properties["ServerState"].Value.ToString())
if (state == ServerState.Stopped || state == ServerState.Paused)
{
    //site is stopped
}
                        {
```